# Outlook Rule Not Working Properly

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

We have an Outlook rule that moves ALL email to a folder. The rule is working fine when email comes from our domain. We have voicemails being delivered to email. When voicemail emails come in, they come from a different domain, and Outlook doesn't move them automatically. If I run the rule manually, it will move the voicemail emails.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only mentioned voicemails.  What happens when other e-mails come in from outside the domain?

Comment: Emails from outside the domain are not delivered to the mailbox. The voicemails are.

Comment: But @Sevens' question is still relevant. Perhaps emails originating outside the domain get moved by the rule, usefully revealing the problem is specific to voicemail messages.

Comment: It would be somewhat useful to eliminate mail from outside the domain but this is for our internal help desk system so I am hesitant to open that up. I may test it.